# setBackButtonBackgroundImage Weard Behaviour on iOS5.1

Tags: ios6, uibarbuttonitem, back-button, ios5.1, uiappearance

I have two différent behaviour on ios5.1 and ios6.0 with

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:offBackButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image: On iOS 6.0 everything is OK]
On iOS 6.0

[image: On iOS5.1 ???]
On iOS 5.1 ???

Is there something I'm not doing well ?

Comment: I, on the other side, have effect in 5.0 that image is cut at the bottom. Changing Insets doesn't make it bigger again (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a stretchable `UIImage` with `UIEdgeInsets` as below:

```
UIImage *normalStateImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)];
UIImage *pressedStateImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-pressed"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:normalStateImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:pressedStateImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

iOS 6.x is clever enough to determine the image sizes and stretch according to it.